# Removing asterisks and single quotes from attribute values using XSL

Tags: string, xslt

I have this XML fragment:

```
<svrl:successful-report test="."
location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][1]/*[local-name()='section']">
```

I want to get the value `@location` and remove the special characters `" *[local-name()=' "` and `" '] "`. In other words, I want the output to be

```
/ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[1]/section
```

I'm currently using this string replace template:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
<xsl:param name="text" />
<xsl:param name="replace" />
<xsl:param name="by" />
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text"
      select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and applying the template like this

```
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@location"/>
                 <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[local-name()='"/>
                 <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>         
            </xsl:call-template>
```

That only gives this result:

```
/*'ClinicalDocument']/*'component']/*'structuredBody']/*'component'][1]/*'section']
```

How can I get the output I want?

Comment: You somehow forgot to mention *how* you're using that string replace template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The other answer to this question is a good one, but has problems with a source XML document like this**:

```
<test xmlns:svrl="my:my">
 <svrl:successful-report test="." location=
 "/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component'][.='abc']"/>
</test>
```

The result it produces when applied on this document is:

```
   /ClinicalDocument/component[.='abc
```

But the correct result is:

```
 /ClinicalDocument/component[.='abc']
```

**This transformation has no problems with the above XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@location">
  <xsl:attribute name="location">
    <xsl:call-template name="makeExplicit">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring(.,2)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="makeExplicit">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="$pText">
   <xsl:variable name="vStep" select="substring-before(concat($pText, '/'), '/')"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="processStep">
     <xsl:with-param name="pStep" select="$vStep"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
   <xsl:call-template name="makeExplicit">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '/')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="processStep">
  <xsl:param name="pStep"/>
  <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pStep, '*['), '*[')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPred" select="substring-after($pStep, '*[local-name()=')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring($vPred, 2), &quot;'&quot;)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vPred, ']')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the above document, the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<test xmlns:svrl="my:my">
   <svrl:successful-report test="." 
      location="/ClinicalDocument/component[.='abc']"/>
</test>
```

Comment: i could not get well with your example

Comment: @user1021885: What is the problem? Just copy and paste the XML and the transformation into your XSLT IDE and perform the transformation -- you should get the correct result.

Comment: /*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument'][.='1']

what does this [.='1'] mean?
in my source document there is only /*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument'],there is not any other characters following the 'ClinicalDocument'

Comment: i got a xml file through schematron validation,then i want to transform this report to html or something like this

Comment: @user1021885: This is just an example of a valid XPath expression -- it has two predicates in the first location step. A solution is more useful if it handles more different cases of input, probably all possible XPath expressions, whose location steps start with `/*[local-name() = 'someName']` . Even though you may not use expressions of the problematic type, it is quite probable that in the future you will do so, as your knowledge of XPath expands and your needs evolve and dictate using richer expressions. Other users of SO would also be interested in such a solution.

Comment: @user1021885: I edited my question and the XML document now is simpler and more understandable. `/ClinicalDocument/component[.='abc']` means: select all `component` elements that are children of the top element named `ClinicalDocument` and whose string value is the string `"abc"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two 'find and replace' here. Firstly you need to remove all of the prefixes ***[local-name()='**, and then you need to remove the suffixes of **']**

You can do this by passing the results of the first **call-template** as a parameter to the second **call-template**

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svrl="my:my">
   <xsl:template match="svrl:successful-report">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
         <xsl:with-param name="text">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@location"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="&quot;*[local-name()='&quot;"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:with-param>
         <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="&quot;']&quot;"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:param name="by"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<test xmlns:svrl="my:my">
   <svrl:successful-report test="." location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][1]/*[local-name()='section']"/>
</test>
```

The following is output

```
/ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[1]/section
```

Comment: @TimC: Good one, but in some cases it has problems -- see an example in my answer.